# Im trying to do a reaction role bot on discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
if(reaction.message.id === "731619243249893417"){
   const guildMember = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
   if(!guildMember.roles.cache.get("692177977705889845")){
       guildMember.roles.add("692177977705889845");
```

Im using this code, but when i react to the message it
don't give me the role, im a starter needing help, thanks u all, and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots only listen for new messages. You have to tell them to listen for an old message explicitly to get a reaction from them. Try using [this code](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages). It fetches the message when a reaction is added to that message.